# Why doesn't XCode accept I have Java?

Tags: android, xcode, spritebuilder

I have just installed SpriteBuilder (latest version) and have the latest version of XCode installed.

From the SpriteBuilder store, I have installed the Android 'pack' which has resulted in being able to deploy to an Android tablet from within XCode.

Problem is, the build always fails and a popup tells me I need Java, takes me to a website to download and install it which I do.

I restart everything but am no further forward. Same error. Have installed Java three times and no change.

Anyone experienced this and got any ideas? :/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824367/why-is-java-not-recognized-after-oracle-jdk-7-is-installed-in-mac-os-lion

Comment: Apple and Java have a complicated relationship. Google it a bit -- you'll find answers.

Comment: In the end, I installed the JDK instead of the runtime (which is what was being requested). Solved the problem. Thanks for the suggestions.